# Restricting Internet access to a domain

Tags: android, proxy, iptables

I'm trying to achieve some sort of proxying in android

I want to route every TCP call in phone to a particulay domain, say example.com

- For example if the user tries to load android.com in the default web
  browser or any other browser like opera mini, it shout show the
  examle.com home page
- Also if user type exaple.com/aboutus.html he should be able to view
  it.
- This Android phone will not have any Internet-required applications
  other than a defined web browser.
- Phone uses public 3G or WiFi connection.

Any Idea?

I think I need to start with linux IP tables, any body can suggest a good starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried these?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#HTTP_PROXY

http://askowen.info/2010/01/how-do-i-set-a-proxy-on-my-android-browser/

http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/programming/android-how-to-set-proxy-for-android-browser/